# How to position Dropdown content behind dropdown button using css

Tags: javascript, css, z-index, reactstrap, jss

How to position Dropdown content behind dropdown button using react jss . I tried using

```
{position: absolute; z-index: 2}
```

for the button and

```
{position:absoulute; zindex:1}
```

for the dropdown content. but it doesn't work.

Comment: z-index isnt the only factor when it comes to which element is on top, its also influenced by display type

Comment: Can you please create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  to help us easily troubleshoot?

Comment: With JSS, the property should be "zIndex" and not "z-index" or "zindex". But like @ChrisLi said it may not be sufficient